# Click event on a widget not working while using a Configure Activity

Tags: android, android-widget

I am having a weather widget which show the temperature of the selected location. In the beginning , a configure activity will be lauched which will give the user an option to select the place he wants.I a using a listview for that.I want a click event for the Widget, which should load my weather application activity.But the problem I am facing is ,the click event is not working when i am using the Configure activity and i am not ale to launch my application on clicking the widget.If i remove the configure activity and launch the widget directly, the click event is working fine and i am able to launch my application.I am starting a service as well to update the widget after certian intervals. This is the code that i am using.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    /** Build the intent to call the service */
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
            UpdateWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

    /** Update the widgets via the service */
     context.startService(intent);


Intent click = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
            Widget.class);      
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            click, 0);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_main);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Widget_layout, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
```

Can anyone help in finding the problem?

Comment: Can you show your Manifest file and Configure class. I think the problem is there.